# Downloaded a bootstrap template , but cant figure out how to make the button send a form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

So Im a new developer, and had to quickly throw a site together for a friend. I downloaded a bootstrap template and modified everything to my liking. However, the theme did not appear to come with any functionality for the submit button on the form that came with the package.

I could not find any PHP files in the theme package, and just want to know how to make the button work when the site is live.

Here is the html that I am working with (this is in bootstrap 3)

---

```html
<section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <hr class="sep">
            <p>Phone Number<br><br></p>
            <a href="tel:1-***-***-****"><h2>***-***-****</h2></a><br><br>
            <hr class="sep">
            <p>Complete the form below to request information<br><br></p>
            <p><em>We respect your privacy - your information will be kept confidential</em></p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text" placeholder="Which class are you interested in?">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text" placeholder="What is the best number to you reach you?">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-block">Send</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: bootstrap wont provide php files. you have write your own php code.

Comment: what you actually want to do with PHP code? Can you explain your expected functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form element `<form>` doesn't know where to submit `action` or how, ie by what `method`.

For example if you want the form to submit to `/text.php` by `post` method then you would use:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
```

You would also need a submit button, which is an `input` with `type="submit"` such as:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
```

Each of your form elements will need a `name` so that their value can be submitted. For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="class_name" id="Text" placeholder="Which class are you interested in?">
</div>
```

(note: currently you have two elements with the same `id` (`id="Text"`) - all ids should be unique)

As for the php script, the posted data will be available on the `$_POST` superglobal. I won't write the code for you since there are many many examples of scripts to send email from a php contact form.

The following are the things the script should do:

- Check all required fields are not empty,
- Validate the submitted values against your requirements (eg message is at least 7 words, email address is a valid email, etc),
- Check for, and prevent, mail header injection attacks,
- Build the message/s html and/or text,
- Set appropriate headers,
- Send the message/s,
- Display the result (success or fail with details) to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Tristan.

Comment: As for the PHP, can you point me in the direction of writing the actual php to run this form? I am a complete newby in terms of PHP.

Comment: And when you say I need a submit button, do I just need to modify the existing submit button to match your code?

Comment: Yes, you should change the submit button to what I provided, and you can change the value to what you want to display. In terms of php script, what do you want it to do? Save the data to file or database, and or send an email containing the information?

Comment: I just need the form the collect the data from all fields and relay it to a personal email account. i.e gmail

Comment: You have been an enormous help Tristan - Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

pls use the input tag submit

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a PHP script that accepts a post from the form but be careful, these days you need to add Google's recaptcha.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Please provide here your findings that can contribute to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Give `name` to all input. This name will help you to **extract values** in next page.
`<form>` require `action` and `method` attribute.

`<input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send' class='btn btn-primary'>` is required to submit data to next page.

**Example**.

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <hr class="sep">
      <p>Phone Number<br><br></p>
      <a href="tel:1-***-***-****"><h2>***-***-****</h2></a><br><br>
      <hr class="sep">
      <p>Complete the form below to request information<br><br></p>
      <p><em>We respect your privacy - your information will be kept confidential</em></p>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
        <form action="SomePage.php" method='POST'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name" name="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text" placeholder="Which class are you interested in?" name="Class_Interested">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text" placeholder="What is the best number to you reach you?" name="Mobile_Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send' class='btn btn-primary'>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**SomePage.php**

```
<?
$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Class_Interested=$_POST['Class_Interested'];
$Mobile_Number=$_POST['Mobile_Number'];
$Message=$_POST['Message'];

echo $Name." ".$Email." ".$Class_Interested." ".$Mobile_Number." ".$Message;

?>
```

> The PHP superglobals $_GET and $_POST are used to collect form-data.

**If method='POST'**

```
<form action="SomePage.php" method='POST'>
..
</form>
```

**SomePage.php**

```
<?
$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Class_Interested=$_POST['Class_Interested'];
$Mobile_Number=$_POST['Mobile_Number'];
$Message=$_POST['Message'];

echo $Name." ".$Email." ".$Class_Interested." ".$Mobile_Number." ".$Message;

?>
```

**If method='GET'**

```
<form action="SomePage.php" method='GET'>
..
</form>
```

**SomePage.php**

```
<?
$Name=$_GET['Name'];
$Email=$_GET['Email'];
$Class_Interested=$_GET['Class_Interested'];
$Mobile_Number=$_GET['Mobile_Number'];
$Message=$_GET['Message'];

echo $Name." ".$Email." ".$Class_Interested." ".$Mobile_Number." ".$Message;

?>
```